# Click update after dialog appears Robotframework

Tags: dialog, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm testing a scenario where I click on a button and below dialog appears. It's only possible to click on 'Update'

[image]

I have put following in my test scenario:

```
    Click Element  jquery=a.newOrder
    Click Element  Link=Update
```

I receive following error message after running the test:
Element is not clickable at point (1023, 127.19999694824219). Other element would receive the click:

The only HTML code that is related to the Update is

```
<a href="orderModule?orderCode=0009502064&amp;edit=true">Update</a>
```

I also try to test this with alert but no alert is found...

Can someone explain me what I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: is it possible that there is more than one link with the text "Update"? Does the update link element have a unique ID you could use instead of the link text?

Comment: Is it possible that you are clicking update while page is still being updated? Element not clickable error on a javascript page seems to point to that direction.

Comment: Hi, I also tried to put wait until page contacts between the code and I still get the same error ...

Click Element  jquery=a.newOrder
 Wait Until Page Contains  Update
 Click Element  Link=Update

Comment: Using wait until might not be enough. In some cases text is there but also a transparent layer is over it and intercepting all clicks. To rule this out use pause execution or sleep before clicking. This is not a final solution but helps to rule out this option.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining your scenario :

When you click update, a pop will be shown. You have to add a Wait until page contains element in any of the elements in pop up and then wait for the element you need to click. After the element is visible and focus is on the element. Click the element. If you get error in this, try to add selenium timeout for command execution speed or add a sleep to check whether the element loads slowly.